How to call Power Point macro function from python without win32com
I'm currently working on a python program (I'm new to python) that modifies a Power Point template that is for official releases.  Unfortunately after my program finishes, I need to run the macro.
My program currently modifies everything that I need in Power Point except running the macro.
When I run the macro after my python program runs, it undoes everything that I did with my program.
FYI, I currently don't have win32com loaded in my version of python (Python 3.8.6 for RHEL 7.x and 8.x) and getting it loaded is not an easy task on my system without a lot of paperwork and time.
Is there a way to run a particular function from the macro without win32com?
